# Using ValueLink with a custom onChange handler in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that uses ReactJS along with `LinkStateMixin` to implement two-way bindings between the form and the underlying model.

This works well, however there are some scenarios where I want additional changes to state to happen when specific field values change - i.e. if I change field 'A', I want to reset field 'B' to something else.

The obvious choice for this is to use a normal `onChange` handler, however since `LinkStateMixin` sets this internally, I cannot override it without breaking the mixin.

Obviously I could simply not use `valueLink` for the relevant components and implement the two-way bindings manually in my onChange handler along with the custom logic, however it would be a lot cleaner to be able to do both.

Is this possible in ReactJS - Or will I need to ditch using `LinkStateMixin` for anything that requires custom event handling logic?

Edit - Added really simple code example

```
fieldAChanged: function(){
    this.setState({ fieldB: '' });
}

render: function(){ return (
    <input valueLink={linkState('fieldA')} onChange={this.fieldAChanged} />
    <input valueLink={linkState('fieldB')}/>
)}
```

My real scenario is somewhat more complex, but in a nutshell this is what I'm trying to do - have `onChange` handler fire when the field is changed, while still using two-way bindings to keep my viewmodel in sync without additional boilerplate. Unfortunately 'valueLink' overrides 'onChange' preventing this from working.

I should also clarify - I'm not asking "what is a possible way to do this", since there's plenty of obvious ways to do it. I'm asking "What is the idiomatic way to do this" in react.

Comment: Can you post code that demonstrates the problem you're seeing? It's difficult to reproduce from a plain text description.

Comment: Added a quick contrived example

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old question, but I wanted to make you aware of a little open source library I wrote to solve this very issue: [reactlink-pipe](https://github.com/idolize/reactlink-pipe)

You can easily have robust functions run before getting or setting values via `valueLink` (whatever you would have done in `onChange`), while at the same time you don't have to give up the syntactic sugar of ReactLink (i.e. you don't have to write a whole bunch of boilerplate `onChange` functions).

For example:

```
var pipeLink = require('reactlink-pipe');

function caps(text) { return text && text.toUpperCase(); }

var WithLink = React.createClass({
  mixins: [LinkedStateMixin],
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { name: 'foo' };
  },
  render: function() {
    // Will display "FOO", while this.state.name will still be "foo"
    return (
      <input type="text" valueLink={pipeLink(caps, this.linkState('name'))} />
    );
  }
});
```

I hope this helps you, or anyone else with a similar problem.